# Webview is stuck when loading new URL

Tags: android, android-webview, nfc

When loading new URL with loadUrl() the titles changes and it seems to be loading the new webpage, but the view is stuck, I can se how the scrollbar moves and the zoom controllers work but the view is just frozen. 
This only happens when a new url is loaded from a **NFC Tag** it's a very strange behaviour, other than that the webview works perfectly. I have to activities the MainActivity sends a broadcast to the WebViewActivity with the new URL but after that the view is stuck, I tried calling the method in the UIThread but it didn't work.

Here's the setup of the webView, also webclient and chrome client are declared in the last block of code.

```
public void setupWebView() {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
}
```

Here's how I call the method loadUrl(), the broadCastReceiver takes care of the NFC intent.

```
    private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};

private WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
        super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
        titleView.setText(view.getTitle());
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        loadNewUrl(intent);
    }
};

    public void loadNewUrl(Intent i) {
    String fullUrl = i.getExtras().getString(Constants.WEB_URL, "");

    progressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.loadUrl(fullUrl);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was overriding the onPause method and every time a NFC is detected it calls this method, causing the UI to pause totally and I also was calling the webview onPause. In my MainActivity I have multiple triggers like geolocation, push notifications and they worked fine, except for the NFC trigger. 
So seems like when a NFC is detected on a Activity it calls onPause on all the other Activities.

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webView.onPause();
}
```

Also in the MainActivity I was using the OnNewIntent() method to catch any intent

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
         //Handles nfc and sends broadcast
    } else if (Constants.INTENT_PUSH_NOITIFICATION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
         //Handles notification and sends broadcast
}
```